# How to store GeoJSON features into individual documents in a collection instead of one document with nested features in Mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, geojson, mongo-shell

I have a GeoJson file in this form (an example is illustrated below):

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [{
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
           "type": "Point",
           "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
       },
       "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0"
       }
   }, {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
           "type": "LineString",
           "coordinates": [
               [102.0, 0.0],
               [103.0, 1.0],
               [104.0, 0.0],
               [105.0, 1.0]
           ]
       },
       "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": 0.0
       }
   }, {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
               [
                   [100.0, 0.0],
                   [101.0, 0.0],
                   [101.0, 1.0],
                   [100.0, 1.0],
                   [100.0, 0.0]
               ]
           ]
       },
       "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": {
               "this": "that"
           }
       }
   }]
 }
```

When I import this file to mongo in one table named `sampledb` 
and in a collection named `samplecol` with this command `mongoimport --db sampledb --collection samplecol --drop --file /home/ec2-user/sample.json`  I execute in mongo shell:

```
db.samplecol.findOne()
```

This command returns all the features. I wonder how I can store the GeoJSON features **into individual documents in a collection** instead of one document with nested features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the expected exact returned documents you'd like, associated to this input you gave?

Comment: Hi @XavierGuihot , the expected return from findOne() command is one record from the whole GeoJson file.